# Get all orders from database - only one row returned

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm trying to get tables to link together to return the email, Order Number, Date, Total Cost and Number of items returned but of the two rows of data I expect to be returned, only one is. The tables are as follows;

```
Table: Customer
+------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| CustomerID | EmailAddress        | DeliveryAddress |
+------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| BLF1       | FredBloggs@NT.co.uk | NULL            |
| SMJ2       | JoeSmith@NT.co.uk   | NULL            |
+------------+---------------------+-----------------+


Table: Item
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| ItemCode | Description | UnitPrice |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1234     | Ring Binder |       1.5 |
| 3456     | Stapler     |      2.99 |
| 8967     | Divider     |       0.5 |
| 9684     | Scissors    |      1.99 |
+----------+-------------+-----------+


Table: ItemOrder
+-------------+----------+---------------+
| OrderNumber | ItemCode | OrderQuantity |
+-------------+----------+---------------+
| 012367      | 1234     |             3 |
| 012367      | 3456     |             1 |
| 012367      | 8967     |             4 |
| 034231      | 3456     |             4 |
| 034231      | 9684     |             2 |
+-------------+----------+---------------+


Table: OnlineOrder
+-------------+------------+------------+
| OrderNumber | CustomerID | OrderDate  |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| 012367      | BLF1       | 2009-05-01 |
| 034231      | SMJ2       | 2009-05-03 |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

The query I run is:

```
SELECT Customer.EmailAddress, 
       OnlineOrder.OrderNumber, 
       OnlineOrder.OrderDate, 
       Count(Item.ItemCode) as TotalItems, 
       FORMAT(SUM(Item.UnitPrice*ItemOrder.OrderQuantity), 2) as TotalPrice
FROM Customer, 
     Item, 
     OnlineOrder, 
     ItemOrder
WHERE OnlineOrder.OrderNumber = ItemOrder.OrderNumber
AND Customer.CustomerID = OnlineOrder.CustomerID
AND Item.ItemCode = ItemOrder.ItemCode;`
```

This only returns one record;

```
+---------------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
| EmailAddress        | OrderNumber | OrderDate  | TotalItems | TotalPrice |      
+---------------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+ 
| FredBloggs@NT.co.uk | 012367      | 2009-05-01 |          5 | 25.43      |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Why won't the query return the second order, with the details and purchaser of that order?

Comment: Better is to use implicit JOIN's the explicit JOIN statement is over 20 years old and the explicit JOIN's are harder to read.

Comment: COUNT() and SUM() without GROUP BY always returns one record..

Comment: Please use proper `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your same query formatted with proper join/on clause.  I also changed the alias references for each table.  Especially for larger table names, it can significantly simplify the readability.

```
SELECT 
      C.EmailAddress, 
      OO.OrderNumber, 
      OO.OrderDate, 
      Count(I.ItemCode) as TotalItems, 
      FORMAT(SUM(I.UnitPrice * IO.OrderQuantity), 2) as TotalPrice
   FROM 
      OnlineOrder OO
         JOIN ItemOrder IO
            ON OO.OrderNumber = IO.OrderNumber
            JOIN Item I
               ON IO.ItemCode = I.ItemCode
         JOIN Customer C
            ON OO.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
   GROUP BY
      OO.OrderNumber
```

The only thing I added was the GROUP BY clause.  Since you want the totals on a per-order basis, the group is by the order.  If you wanted the total to be per the customer, you would need to remove the explicit order number and date to see ALL the order items and all line item totals.

Answer (score -1):

I reproduced your data and SQL using ANSI joins and got the right answer, two records. I have no idea what you did wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    customerid VARCHAR (10)
  , emailaddress VARCHAR (50)
  , deliveryaddress VARCHAR (100)
);

INSERT INTO customer (
           customerid, emailaddress, deliveryaddress
            )
     VALUES (
                'BLF1', 'FredBloggs@NT.co.uk', NULL
            );

INSERT INTO customer (
           customerid, emailaddress, deliveryaddress
            )
     VALUES (
                'SMJ2', 'JoeSmith@NT.co.uk', NULL
            );

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE item
(
    itemcode NUMBER
  , description VARCHAR (50)
  , unitprice DECIMAL (10, 2)
);

INSERT INTO item (
           itemcode, description, unitprice
            )
     VALUES (
                1234, 'Ring Binder', 1.5
            );

INSERT INTO item (
           itemcode, description, unitprice
            )
     VALUES (
                3456, 'Stapler', 2.99
            );

INSERT INTO item (
           itemcode, description, unitprice
            )
     VALUES (
                8967, 'Divider', .5
            );

INSERT INTO item (
           itemcode, description, unitprice
            )
     VALUES (
                9684, 'Scissors', 1.99
            );

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE itemorder
(
    ordernumber VARCHAR (10)
  , itemcode INTEGER
  , orderquantity INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO itemorder (
           ordernumber, itemcode, orderquantity
            )
     VALUES (
                '012367', 1234, 3
            );

INSERT INTO itemorder (
           ordernumber, itemcode, orderquantity
            )
     VALUES (
                '012367', 3456, 1
            );

INSERT INTO itemorder (
           ordernumber, itemcode, orderquantity
            )
     VALUES (
                '012367', 8967, 4
            );

INSERT INTO itemorder (
           ordernumber, itemcode, orderquantity
            )
     VALUES (
                '034231', 3456, 4
            );

INSERT INTO itemorder (
           ordernumber, itemcode, orderquantity
            )
     VALUES (
                '034231', 9684, 2
            );

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE onlineorder
(
    ordernumber VARCHAR (10)
  , customerid VARCHAR (10)
  , orderdate DATE
);

INSERT INTO onlineorder (
           ordernumber, customerid, orderdate
            )
     VALUES (
                '012367', 'BLF1', DATE '2009-05-01'
            );

INSERT INTO onlineorder (
           ordernumber, customerid, orderdate
            )
     VALUES (
                '034231', 'SMJ2', DATE '2009-05-03'
            );

COMMIT;

  SELECT customer.emailaddress
       , onlineorder.ordernumber
       , onlineorder.orderdate
       , COUNT (item.itemcode) AS totalitems
       , SUM (item.unitprice * itemorder.orderquantity) AS totalprice
    FROM customer
         INNER JOIN onlineorder ON customer.customerid = onlineorder.customerid
         INNER JOIN itemorder ON itemorder.ordernumber = onlineorder.ordernumber
         INNER JOIN item ON item.itemcode = itemorder.itemcode
--   WHERE onlineorder.ordernumber = itemorder.ordernumber
--     AND customer.customerid = onlineorder.customerid
--     AND item.itemcode = itemorder.itemcode
GROUP BY customer.emailaddress, onlineorder.ordernumber, onlineorder.orderdate;
```